# Single adjective for containing a lot of text (digital)

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word for a graphic, screen, picture, document, etc. that contains a lot of text. Specifically for digital media. The context is that I've noticed that the Walgreens pin pad display has a lot of text and words all over the screen and I was wondering if there is a word to describe it.

e.g. sentence: "Wow that image is very *_*".

I thought maybe wordy, textual, or texty but those don't sound right. Maybe textful?

Comment: Milo: can I commend you for requesting 'I was wondering if there is a word for ...' rather than demanding 'What is the word for ...'. I wish all SWRs were as elegantly phrased.

Comment: What is it about "wordy" that you don't like? What does it fail to capture?

Comment: @CanisLupus well the text on the screen isn't always a word.

Comment: One day soon the adjective, texty, meaning "a lot of text" will be popularized. Mark my words. Just a question of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *text-laden, text-heavy, text-filled* or *text-burdened*.

Some more general terms you can use to describe a messy screen are *busy-looking*, *cluttered, chaotic* and *visually confusing.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that wordy is best:

> Using or expressed in too many words.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20wordy)

However there is also

> verbose
>   Using or expressed in more words than are needed.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20verbose)

And

> circumlocution
>   The use of many words where fewer would do, especially in a deliberate attempt to be vague or evasive.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20circumlocution)

<sup>Found with the help of [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/), [with their the reverse search](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml), by searching [*"has lots of words"*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=has+lots+of+words)</sup>